# Javascript google spreadsheet: set the value of cell based on a match

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm creating a world cup bracket in `google` spreadsheet and want to set the value of a cell based on the value of two cells matching.

My code below sets the value of the cell 02 regardless of the cells matching (B3 & B10).

I'm not sure how to fix?

```
    function groupAA() {

       var ss           = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
       var sheet        = ss.getActiveSheet();
       var groupA       = ss.getRangeByName("groupA");
       var groupAvalues = groupA.getValues();
       var winnerA      = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
       var runnerUpA    = sheet.getRange('B3').getValue();
       var guessWinnerA = sheet.getRange('B10').getValue();




      for (var i=0; i < groupAvalues.length; i++) {
      var winnerGroupA = groupAvalues[i];
    if(winnerGroupA == guessWinnerA){
      setPoints('o2', '2');
    }
   }

  } 

    function setPoints(rangeName, value){
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(rangeName).setValue(value)

}
```

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective .

Comment: function setPoints(rangeName, value){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(rangeName).setValue(value);
} 

}

Comment: What are you assigning to "groupA"? I get the same result if I assign both the runnerup and the winner to groupA.  In otherwords, this will only work if you assign only winners to groupA.

Comment: I'm using a range defined in the sheet which is consists of the teams in group A "Brazil, Croatia, Mexico, Cameroon"

Comment: Exactly, this is your problem.  Croatia is in the list which you are iterating through.  If I picked Croatia, crazy though I may be, you will pass the if statement because Croatia is matched on the second pass.

Comment: I dont think thats it i've edited the range and just put brazil, but it still does the calculation even if the cell B10 is empty

Comment: If you have blanks in the range where you "just put brazil" you will get it to pass when it is blank.  Look at Logger.log() you will see what is going on.  You will need to initialize the cell to 0 too before you run through the for statement... Don't forget that.

Comment: Added a code example for you...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a logic problem.  Please look at what you are assigning to groupA.  I get the same result if I assign both the runnerup and the winner to groupA (as the world cup is designed). In otherwords, this will only work if you assign *only* winners to groupA.

Note this line `var winnerGroupA = groupAvalues[i];`. Because you are iterating through all of groupA and assigning each value to winnerGroupA.  You are essentially saying that everyone wins.

Here is an example that I worked up for you.

```
function groupAA() 
{

  var ss           = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet        = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var groupA       = ss.getRangeByName("groupA");
  var winners = ss.getRangeByName("winners");
  var guesses = ss.getRangeByName("guesses");
  var guessesAvalues = guesses.getValues();
  var groupAvalues = groupA.getValues();
  var winnersAvalues = winners.getValues();
  var winnerA      = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
  var runnerUpA    = sheet.getRange('B3').getValue();
  var guessWinnerA = sheet.getRange('B10').getValue();

  setPoints('o2', '0');
  for (var i =0; i< guessesAvalues.length; i++)
  {


    for (var j=0; j < winnersAvalues.length; j++) {

      if((winnersAvalues[j].toString() == guessesAvalues[i].toString())&&(winnersAvalues[j]!=''&&winnersAvalues[j]!=null))
      {

        var currentRange =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('o2');        
        setPoints('o2', currentRange.getCell(1,1).getValue()+Number(2));

      }
    }
  }
} 

function setPoints(rangeName, value){
  Logger.log(value);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(rangeName).setValue(value);

}

function onEdit(){
  groupAA();
}
```

So I created a range of winners, and range of guesses (the lengths of which are arbitrary).  See the following picture to see the spreadsheet layout (I don't know if Mexico won yet, so don't tell me):

[image]

You'll notice I added an initialization of the score to 0 at the front.  I also converted to strings, though you probably don't have to do this.  I then check to make sure that one of the winning teams isn't blank and if all of this passes, I'm going to increment the score up by 2 as you expressed an interest.  You will also notice that I added onEdit() to call the groupAA() so that it will update auto-magically when you add your guesses, in this way you can see the result of getting them all right, all wrong, and some right.  The following is an example of a losing guess:

[image]

Comment: To fix this,... you need a list/range holding the winners only then replace "groupAvalues" with this range.